# Break out of a while loop that contains a switch statement

Tags: c#, while-loop, break

I am having trouble figuring out how to break out of a loop that contains a switch statement.  Break breaks out of the switch, not the loop.

There is probably a more elegant solution to this.  I have implemented a flag that starts out as true and gets set to false and ends the loop.  Can you offer a better solution?

Background: this code is used in a bar code workflow system.  We have PocketPCs that have bar code scanners built in.  This code is used in one of those functions.  It prompts the user for different pieces of data throughout the routine.  This piece allows them to scroll through some inventory records displaying that info on the PocketPC terminal (paged results) and allows them to enter "D" for Done, "Q" to quit.

Here is the current C# example that needs to be improved:

```
do
{
    switch (MLTWatcherTCPIP.Get().ToUpper())
    {
        case "": //scroll/display next inventory location
            MLTWatcherTCPIP.TerminalPrompt.ScrollBodyTextDown();
            break;
        case "P": //scroll/display previous inventory location
            MLTWatcherTCPIP.TerminalPrompt.ScrollBodyTextDown();
            break;
        case "D": //DONE (exit out of this Do Loop)
            // break; // this breaks out of the switch, not the loop
            // return; // this exists entire method; not what I'm after
            keepOnLooping = false;
            break;
        case "Q": //QUIT (exit out to main menu)
            return;
        default:
            break;
    }
} while (keepOnLooping);
```

Here is an example of code that does this in VB.NET

```
Do
    Select Case MLTWatcherTCPIP.Get().ToUpper
        Case "" ''#scroll/display next inventory location
            MLTWatcherTCPIP.TerminalPrompt.ScrollBodyTextDown()
        Case "P" ''#scroll/display previous inventory location
            MLTWatcherTCPIP.TerminalPrompt.ScrollBodyTextUp()
        Case "D" ''#DONE (exit out of this Do Loop)
            Exit Do
        Case "Q" ''#QUIT (exit out to main menu)
            Return
    End Select
Loop
```

Thanks,

Comment: This looks fine to me, a flag variable is a standard way to check a loop condition.

Comment: In Java (and some others), labeling the loop and using a [labelled break](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/branch.html) would be the most straightforward answer.

Answer (score 56, accepted):

I find this form to be ever-so-slightly more readable:

```
bool done = false;
while (!done) 
{ 
    switch (MLTWatcherTCPIP.Get().ToUpper()) 
    { 
        case "": //scroll/display next inventory location 
            MLTWatcherTCPIP.TerminalPrompt.ScrollBodyTextDown(); 
            break; 
        case "P": //scroll/display previous inventory location 
            MLTWatcherTCPIP.TerminalPrompt.ScrollBodyTextDown(); 
            break; 
        case "D": //DONE (exit out of this Do Loop) 
            done = true;
            break; 
        case "Q": //QUIT (exit out to main menu) 
            return; 
        default: 
            break; 
    } 
}
```

Comment: Why not `if/else`?

Comment: @Ozkan I was just answering the question as it was given. I would actually never use ToUpper() in this manner to do case-insensitive comparisons.

Answer (score 58):

I'd try to avoid it, but you could use...

## goto

However, angry mobs with pitchforks become an occupational hazard if you choose to do so.

Comment: More than 15 years of experience tell me that sometimes goto is the best, fast and optimized option, keep the algorithm in one small place: keep it fast, efficient, atomic, without destroying it in a thousand pieces, reduce unnecessary calls.
Examples, acoustic wave analysis, machine vision, real-time, etc.
A flag will not make it slower, I see it as impossible, but many flags can be a reading problem.

Answer (score 32):

One option here is to refactor this loop into a method ("extract method"), and use `return`.

Answer (score 12):

The only other way I know of is the dreaded goto.  [MSDN also says this.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa664758(VS.71).aspx)

However, I see no reason why you'd use it in this case.  The way you have implemented works fine, and is more maintainable than a goto.  I would keep what you have.

Comment: While `goto` may be dreaded, there are a small number of cases where it is actually useful and I believe this is one of them.

Answer (score 10):

You must use a goto statement for multi level breaks. It appears to be the only 'clean' way in C#. Using a flag is also useful, but requires extra code if the loop has other predicaments for running.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa664756(VS.71).aspx

It may be interesting to note that some other non-c languages have multi level breaks by doing `break levels;` (Java is just as useless, though, as it uses a goto disguised as a continue.. :P)

Answer (score 9):

You can't easily break out of the outer loop, but you can `continue` it.

If you reverse your logic then you get this. 
Note there is a `break` immediately after the switch statement to exit the loop.

This isn't very readable code in my opinion, and I think a flag is still best.

```
   do
         {
            switch (Console.ReadKey().KeyChar.ToString())
            {
                case "U":
                    Console.WriteLine("Scrolling up");
                    continue;

                case "J":
                    Console.WriteLine("Scrolling down");
                    continue;

                case "D": //DONE (exit out of this Do Loop)
                    break;

                case "Q": //QUIT (exit out to main menu)
                    return;

                default:
                    Console.WriteLine("Continuing");
                    continue;
            }

            break;

        } while (true);

        Console.WriteLine("Exited");
```

Comment: Interesting and original approach, never thought of such technique, who knows maybe useful in some cases !

Comment: @AlexisMartial I'm sure there's cases where this would be the best answer but it sure is giving me a headache looking at it again after ... no way was it that long ago!

Answer (score 8):

Why not wrap the switch into a method that returns a boolean to keep on looping?  It would have the side benefit of making the code more readable.  There's a reason someone wrote a paper saying we don't need goto statements after all ;)

```
do
{
    bool keepOnLooping = TryToKeepLooping();
} while (keepOnLooping);

private bool TryToKeepLooping()
{
    switch (MLTWatcherTCPIP.Get().ToUpper())
    {
        case "": //scroll/display next inventory location
            MLTWatcherTCPIP.TerminalPrompt.ScrollBodyTextDown();
            break;
        case "P": //scroll/display previous inventory location
            MLTWatcherTCPIP.TerminalPrompt.ScrollBodyTextDown();
            break;
        case "D": //DONE (exit out of this Do Loop)
            // break; // this breaks out of the switch, not the loop
            // return; // this exists entire method; not what I'm after
            return false;
        case "Q": //QUIT (exit out to main menu)
            return true;
        default:
            break;
    }

    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

A flag is the standard way to do this.  The only other way I know of is to use a `goto`.

Answer (score 4):

You can replace the `switch` statement with an `if/else` statement.  No `goto` needed and the `break` statement leaves the loop:

```
do
{
  String c = MLTWatcherTCPIP.Get().ToUpper();

  if (c = "")
    MLTWatcherTCPIP.TerminalPrompt.ScrollBodyTextDown();
  else if (c = "P")
    MLTWatcherTCPIP.TerminalPrompt.ScrollBodyTextUp();
  else if (c = "D")
     break;
  else if (c = "Q")
    return;
  else
  {
    // Handle bad input here.
  }
} while (keepLooping)
```

Comment: While this is fine for most applications, there is an important difference between `switch` and `if/else` being that the compiler can usually optimize the "branching" operations by using a jump table, resulting in faster code.

Comment: Steve, the code here is waiting for user input. It's already sat there for billions of nanoseconds doing absolutely nothing. Whether it takes one or one hundred nanoseconds to work out what the character typed was seems completely irrelevant. Optimizations should be driven by empirical data about real world user concerns, not by armchair guesses about what the compiler might do.

Comment: I agree with Steve's argument but in certain simple situations changing your logic to if/else would do the trick.

Answer (score 1):

IMO, this seems a perfectly fine way of breaking out of a `while` loop. It does what you expect with no side effects. I could think of doing

```
if(!keepOnLooping)
  break;
```

But that's not really any different in terms of execution.

Answer (score 1):

Wrap it into a function and use a return statement to exit. How about that?

Answer (score 1):

Write something like:

```
case "Exit/Break" :
                  //Task to do
                    if(true)
                      break;
```

This break will not be associated with any case. It will belong to the `while` loop.

Answer (score 0):

You could change the switch statement to a for/foreach loop. Once the condition is met set "keepOnLooping" to false and then use break to get out of the loop. The rest should take care of itself.

Comment: switch to for/foreach? You meant something else.

Answer (score 0):

Another (not so great) alternative is to uniquely handle the `case` where you have to "break out of the loop" with an `if` straight away and move it out of the `switch` block. Not terribly elegant if the switch-case is very long:

```
do
{
    var expression = MLTWatcherTCPIP.Get().ToUpper();
    if (expression = "D") //DONE (exit out of this Do Loop)
    {   
        statement;
        break;
    }

    switch (expression)
    {
        case "": //scroll/display next inventory location
            MLTWatcherTCPIP.TerminalPrompt.ScrollBodyTextDown();
            break;
        case "P": //scroll/display previous inventory location
            MLTWatcherTCPIP.TerminalPrompt.ScrollBodyTextDown();
            break;
        case "Q": //QUIT (exit out to main menu)
            return;
        default:
            break;
    }
} while (true); //or whatever your condition is
```

You can also make the `case` itself a part of the condition of `while` loop considering you only have to break out of the loop and the computation of expression itself is trivial (like reading a variable).

```
do
{
    switch (expression)
    {
        case "": //scroll/display next inventory location
            MLTWatcherTCPIP.TerminalPrompt.ScrollBodyTextDown();
            break;
        case "P": //scroll/display previous inventory location
            MLTWatcherTCPIP.TerminalPrompt.ScrollBodyTextDown();
            break;
        case "Q": //QUIT (exit out to main menu)
            return;
        default:
            break;
    }
} while (condition && expression != "D");
```

---

Also if refactoring the entire thing into a new method (which is the most elegant solution to this) is unacceptable for some reason, then you can also rely on an anonymous delegate to do the same inside the existing method.

Answer (score -2):

May or may not work but lamda why not give it a shot just for fun

```
while(  (expr) => (){
switch(expr){
case 1: dosomething; return true; 
case 2 : something;return true;
case exitloop:return false;}
});
```