# Breaking out of a 'for' loop from a ''case" statement

Tags: c#

I was asked to do maintenance work on some C# code which, I'm told, was originally converted from Visual Basic 6.  (I mention this only because I don't know VB6 so I don't know if it would have made more sense in that language. . .)

It's got a *for* loop which parses some text for a proprietary scripting language by using a *switch* inside the *for* loop . . .

```
for ( t = 0; t < upperBound(tokens); t++)
{
    String mystring = tokens[t];
    switch (mystring)  
    {
        case "GOTO":
            if (firstGoto == -1)
            {
                firstGoto = t;
            } 
            else
            {
                // compute number of tokens in GOTO
                pointLength = t - firstGoto - 1;
                break;  // exit for
            }
            break;
       case "ACTUATE"
 . . .
```

Notice the comment

> ```
>    // exit for
> ```

The programmer expects the *break* will exit the *for* loop but I think it will only exit the *switch* statement because the documentation for *break* says

*The break statement terminates the closest enclosing loop or switch statement in which it appears. Control is passed to the statement that follows the terminated statement, if any.*

So am I correct that this will only exit the *switch*, but still be in the *for*, and if so, what is the correct way to do what the original programmer intended?

Comment: Surely you could figure this out by either running the code or writing a simple test harness to see what happens?

Comment: Is your question "Am I correct", or is it "How can I..."? For the latter, see [Break out of a while loop that contains a switch statement](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1987379/break-out-of-a-while-loop-that-contains-a-switch-statement).

Comment: The correct way (IMO) is to encapsulate this for loop in a method and return from the method

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, break will break out of the closest loop or switch. The easiest way is to use a goto. (No, goto is not evil)

```
for {
switch(...) {
        ....
        goto MyLabel;
    }
}
MyLabel:
```

Comment: +1 for bravery.  Not to mention that switch is really just a structured set of goto's.

Comment: @Smeegs Many statements are goto's in disguise (return, break, continue, if-else) I don't understand the anti-goto movement. It's like racism: everyone is allowed to jump unless your name is goto. :)

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you are correct... break will only exit the innermost block of code.

One easy way to do this is to also have a boolean flag which is set within the switch statement, and at the end of the loop just do this:

```
var flag = false;
for (...) {

    switch (...) {
        case "x":
            flag = true;
    }        

    if (flag) break;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes break will only terminate the switch in this scenario. How about using a boolean to exit the for as well..?

```
for ( t = 0; t < upperBound(tokens); t++)
{
String mystring = tokens[t];
bool exitFor = false;
switch (mystring)  
{
    case "GOTO":
        if (firstGoto == -1)
        {
            firstGoto = t;
        } 
        else
        {
            // compute number of tokens in GOTO
            pointLength = t - firstGoto - 1;
            exitFor = true;
            break;  // exit for
        }
        break;
   case "ACTUATE"

. . .

if(exitFor)
    break;
```