# Is it possible to manage loop with a switch statement?

Tags: c#, loops, switch-statement, break, continue

I want to control a while loop, if the result is "Continue" I want to do nothing, if it is "Retry" I want to skip the step, if it is "Finish" I want to break the loop.

The problem is the switch statement itself is using the "break" and "continue" keywords that I need to manage my loop.

```cs
while(some bool)
{
   var result = GetResult(...);
   switch(result)
   {
      case MyResult.Continue:
      //do nothing
      break;
      case MyResult.Retry:
      // continue the loop
      break;
      case MyResult.Finish:
      // break the loop
      break;
   }
}
```

Is this even possible or should I just do this with if else statements (after all, the scope of possible Results is not so big)?

Edit:

A.d. "Skip the step":
Well, I wanted to over-generalize the process. Actually if the result is "Continue" I want to do execute some code, the merit of the question was if it is possible to use 'break' and 'continue' to control a loop from within the switch statement.
So yes, the answer is already in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1987379/break-out-of-a-while-loop-that-contains-a-switch-statement)

Comment: what's the difference between do nothing and continue the loop?

Comment: "skip the step", *which* step?

Comment: have you tried? does it work?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1987379/break-out-of-a-while-loop-that-contains-a-switch-statement

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is a little unclear around "*skip the step*" as you've not specified what this *actually means* but yes you can totally use a switch to manage the loop condition

```
bool continueLoop = true;
while(continueLoop)
{
   var result = GetResult(...);
   switch(result)
   {
      case MyResult.Continue:
      //do nothing
      break;
      case MyResult.Retry:
      // continue the loop
      break;
      case MyResult.Finish:
      // break the loop
      continueLoop = false;
      break;
   }
}
```

Comment: or even `for(bool continueLoop = true; continueLoop;) {...}` instead of `bool continueLoop = true; while(continueLoop) {...}`

Comment: In general case `continueLoop = false; continue;` in case we have some code after `switch`: `while(...) {...switch(result) {} some_code_here}`